# Passing by reference: child of multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, multiple-inheritance

I'm getting build errors when passing an object that implements multiple interface to a function that requires only one of the interfaces.

I'm developing a communication package.
The package has a Receiver class and a Sender Class.  The Receiver class uses a notification interface Receive_Notifier (function object) for handling notifications.  Likewise the Sender class uses a notification interface Send_Notifier to handling notifications.

```
interface Send_Notifier
{
    void sending_text(string text);
}

interface Receive_Notifier
{
    void raw_text_received(string raw_text);
}

class Sender
{
    Send_Notifier m_notifier = null;
    public Sender(ref Send_Notifier notifier)
    {
        m_notifier = notifier;
    }
    public void send(string text)
    {
        m_notifier.sending_text(text);
        return;
    }
}

class Receiver
{
    Receive_Notifier m_notifier = null;
    public Sender(ref Receive_Notifier notifier)
    {
        m_notifier = notifier;
    }
    public void receive(string text)
    {
        m_notifier.raw_text_received(text);
        return;
    }
}
```

I have combined the interfaces into a Communications_Notifier:

```
interface Communications_Notifier
    : Send_Notifier, Receive_Notifier
{
}
```

I created a `Notifier` class that implements the `Communications_Notifier` interface:

```
class Notifier
    : Communications_Notifier
{
    public void sending_text(string text)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("--> " + text);
    }
    public void raw_text_received(string raw_text)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("<-- " + raw_text);
    }
}
```

To simplify this post, I'll only show the sender class:

```
class Sender
{
    Send_Notifier m_notifier = null;
    public Sender(ref Send_Notifier notifier)
    {
        m_notifier = notifier;
    }
    public void send(string text)
    {
        m_notifier.sending_text(text);
        return;
    }
}
```

The issue is when I pass an instance of the `Notifier` to an instance of the `Sender` class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Notifier the_notifier = new Notifier();
        Sender talker = new Sender(ref the_notifier); // ** Error generating line

        talker.send("Hello\n");

        string pause_text;
        pause_text = System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The errors from Visual C# Express 2010:

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'Multiple_Inheritance_Interface.Sender.Sender(ref Multiple_Inheritance_Interface.Send_Notifier)' has some invalid arguments    C:\Users\Thomas\Programming_Experiments\C_Sharp\Multiple_Inheritance_Interface\Multiple_Inheritance_Interface\Program.cs    55  29  Multiple_Inheritance_Interface  
Error   2   Argument '1': cannot convert from 'ref Multiple_Inheritance_Interface.Notifier' to 'ref Multiple_Inheritance_Interface.Send_Notifier'   C:\Users\Thomas\Programming_Experiments\C_Sharp\Multiple_Inheritance_Interface\Multiple_Inheritance_Interface\Program.cs    55  44  Multiple_Inheritance_Interface
```

### Questions:

1. Why can't the `Notifier` be
   converted to a reference of type
   `Sender`, since it implements the
   `Sender` interface?
2. Why is the argument to the
   constructor invalid?

*Note:  I'm transitioning from a C++, C and Java background to C#.*

Comment: I don't see the `Sender` interface. I only see a class.

Comment: Is the constructor `public Sender(ref Receive_Notifier notifier)`actually this way in the `Receiver` class?

Comment: As a sidenote: Consider prefixing your interfaces with an `I`. That's the naming convention in .net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ref` parameters support no co- or contra-variance. This is necessary since it can both read and change the reference. So if you passed in a derived class, and the function assigned a new instance that's not of that derived type your code would break.

Example:

```
void MakeCat(ref Animal animal)
{
  animal=new Cat();
}

Dog dog=new Dog();
MakeCat(ref dog);
```

This obviously can't work since now you'd have a `Cat` in your `dog` variable.

---

I'm not sure why you're using `ref` in the first place. With reference types you already can change the content of the instance passed in. You just can't replace the variable passed in with a new instance of that reference type.

---

`out` parameters on the other hand look like they could be covariant. I suspect that they aren't is due to a limitation in the runtime: They are really `ref` parameters marked with an attribute telling the compiler to treat it as an `out` parameter.

Comment: He's using `ref` because he's "*transitioning from a C++, C and Java background to C#.*"

Comment: Kind of.  I'm using a `ref` because I want the classes and functions to refer to a single instance instead of passing copies everywhere.

Comment: Ok in C++ the `ref` would make sense, in Java on the other hand behaves like C# in that respect.

Comment: @Thomas Even without `ref` there is only one shared instance. Since all classes are reference types. You could imagine that you're always implicitly using a pointer, and never work with the actual object. (Applies only to reference types, not value types, see mquander's answer for details)

Comment: Grrrhh.  In C++, when I pass a reference to an object, I can modify the contents of the object, but can't *reseat* or assign an new object to it.  The reference will always refer to the object.  In C++, to perform the functionality that is shown, I would pass a reference to the pointer, so I could modify the pointer by assigning a new instance.

Comment: Since you always work with pointers in C# you basically constructed a pointer to a pointer to your object by using a `ref` param. A C# reference type behaves more like a C++ pointer than like a C++ reference.

Answer (score 4):

You are misusing `ref`.  In C#, only `struct`s are "passed by value" in a traditional sense.  By default, object references are passed to methods.  For example:

```
class HypotheticalSender
{
    Send_Notifier m_notifier = null;

    public HypotheticalSender(Send_Notifier notifier) // no "ref"
    {
        m_notifier = notifier;
    }
}

// ...

HypotheticalSender talker = new HypotheticalSender(the_notifier);

the_notifier.InstanceProperty = "foobar";

// since talker's reference points to the same object, it sees "foobar" too
```

So there's no need at all for the `ref` keyword in your constructor.

This is similar to Java's behavior, and dissimilar to C and C++'s behavior.

Comment: Exactly. To the OP: C# and C++ have a different meaning for references. In some sense when you pass an object by reference in C#, you are passing a reference to the variable that holds the reference to the object... Hope that makes sense. A double pointer/reference if you will. Here's a handy explanation: http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Comment: C# references behave almost like C++ pointers, except you don't have pointer arithmetic on them, and you can't directly dereference them. (In `safe` code).

Comment: +1 If I could, I would accept this answer in addition to CodeInChaos' answer too.  Combined, they answer my issue. The chosen answer illustrates a unique difference between C# and C++ which can cause more problems. :-(

Comment: By default, both structs and classes are passed by value. It's just that with classes, the value being passed is the reference pointer to the classes instance's location in memory.

Comment: I agree, Matthew, but that is strikingly different to the semantics implied in C++ when someone refers to "passing by value."